# An Error while logging hosting asp core as a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logging

I'm hosting an asp.core app `.net 5.0` published in a single file as a windows service. I added this is my `program.cs`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logger =>
            {
                logger.AddConsole();
                logger.AddEventSourceLogger();
                logger.AddLog4Net("log4net.config", true);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
        .UseWindowsService();
```

but when I am running it in the console or as a service with **admin account** it works fine  but when I'm running it as a service with **local system** I get the following error which I guess it can't create the entry in the **EventLog** so how do I get around this?

> 2021-03-08 11:36:14,917 [16] ERROR Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel - Unhandled exception while processing 0HM72A139U7NB.
> System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (The source 'server' is not registered in log 'Application'. (It is registered in log 'System'.) " The Source and Log properties must be matched, or you may set Log to the empty string, and it will automatically be matched to the Source property.NoAccountInfo=Cannot obtain account information.)
> ---> System.ArgumentException: The source 'server' is not registered in log 'Application'. (It is registered in log 'System'.) " The Source and Log properties must be matched, or you may set Log to the empty string, and it will automatically be matched to the Source property.NoAccountInfo=Cannot obtain account information.
> at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.VerifyAndCreateSource(String sourceName, String currentMachineName)
> at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance, Byte[] data, Object[] values)
> at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance, Object[] values)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.WindowsEventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.WriteMessage(String message, EventLogEntryType eventLogEntryType, Int32 eventId)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter) at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.<Log>g__LoggerLog|12_0[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, ILogger logger, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter, List`1& exceptions, TState& state) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.ThrowLoggingError(List`1 exceptions)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.KestrelTrace.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.Log(ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception, String message, Object[] args)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogCritical(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, Exception exception, String message, Object[] args)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 httpApplication) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.KestrelConnection`1.ExecuteAsync()

Comment: what is your log4net.config?

Comment: a file logger the issue is the logging to the systems EventLog that getting logged when  running it as a service as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-configuration